# How to assign Http Response in .net core 2.0 ActionExecutingContext

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I was creating ActionFilterAttribute for my .net core 2.0 project to filter all api request and token authorization. my problem is , if any any user not acceptable to access the api, ActionExecutingContext will return Not Acceptable 406 status. Is there any class for Not Acceptable Result. Thanks in Advance.

**ActionFilterAttribute**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class AuthorizationRequiredAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
         context.Result = //place your code here, which return NotAcceptable Status
         base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `new StatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally working with StatusCodeResult

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class AuthorizationRequiredAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
         context.Result = new StatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable);
         base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }

}
```